# How can I print HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap, multimap

I have tried this

```
ScreenDumpParser dump = new ScreenDumpParser();
    Map btn_bound = dump.parse();

    Iterator iterator = btn_bound.keySet().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       String key = iterator.next().toString();
       List<Integer> value = btn_bound.get(key);

       System.out.println(key);
    }
```

but this line

```
List<Integer> value = btn_bound.get(key);
```

gives error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to List<Integer>
```

I need to print all the values along with the key in one single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a value to your List you should use:

`value.add( btn_bound.get(key));`

and if the button is a list or something else you must add more then one value to your list with

`value.addRange( btn_bound.get(key));`

And if you want to get a value:

```
Object foo = value.get(btn_bound.get(key));
```

Comment: Casting is completely unnecessary here. And this `List<Integer> value = new List<Integer>(btn_bound.get(key));` is wrong (mind that OPs question is in Java).

Comment: When I wrote the answer the language tag was missing so i wrote for Java and C# but i edit

Comment: Yeah, I know that the tag was missing, so no worries :). When you write something for two languages, then clearly write which part belongs to which language. The `new List<..>(...)` part clearly not for Java (for example).